# PHP starting tmux session

Tags: php, terminal, tmux

I have tried to start tmux session in php:

```
<?php
passthru('tmux new -d -s test');
system('tmux new -d -s test');
exec('tmux new -d -s test');
shell_exec('tmux new -d -s test');
escapeshellcmd('tmux new -d -s test');
?>
```

And it and does not work. Does anyone had similar issue, and how to solve it?

Comment: `And it and does not work` That is kind of vague. Some of those commands give you an output. Is there any error returned from them? Do you have `tmux` installed?

Comment: If you're running this through a browser, the webserver user probably does not have access to tmux, or to a login session.

Comment: I get only "tmux new -d -s test" from escapeshellcmd() when am echo it, I have no result from others methods, and yes i have tmux instaled, it works when im starting the comand in terminal but in PHP dosent work.

Comment: i had tried the same thing  in laravel and when i start php artisan serve it works

Comment: `php artisan` runs as a user account, or root, depending on how you run it. The user that Apache/nginx runs under usually does not have login rights, so cannot start screen sessions.

Comment: how can i solve it in php? do you have some idea?

Comment: No idea, but that's also something I wouldn't recommend, because Bad Things could happen.